# Does powershell have any exceptions while working with IE 11? Why would getElementByID, tagname, or even IHTML3 not work?

Tags: html, powershell, authentication, automation, getelementbyid

Below is the code and html page details:
I am using IE11 and powershell version 5. The same logic works fine for facebook login on my personal machine but not on my org system. I was not able to get any additional details on what might prohibit the code from fetching the id labels of the page.

```
    $username = "user1" 
    $password = "pass" 
    $url="my application url"
    $ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
    $ie.visible=$true
    $ie.navigate($url)
    while($ie.ReadyState -eq 4) 
    {
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 10;
    }
    $ie.visible = $false
    $ie.visible = $true
    $ie.document.getElementById('login-form-username').value= "$username"
    $ie.document.getElementById('login-form-login-password').value = "$password"
    $ie.document.getElementById('login-form-login').click()


    The html looks like below:

    <input class="input-field" id="login-form-username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" tabindex="0"> <br>
                <input class="input-field" id="login-form-login-password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="0"> <br>


            <div class="input-field" style="border:none; padding-left: 0px" id="servers-input-field">
                <select id="login-form-servers" style="width: 300px; display: none;" tabindex="0">

                        <option value="Default Client">Default Client</option>

                </select><span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" id="login-form-servers-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="login-form-servers-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 298px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Default Client</span></span>
            </div>



            <div class="rememberMeContainer">
                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberme-checkbox" class="rememberMeCheck" tabindex="0">
                <label for="rememberme-checkbox">Remember me</label>
            </div>
    enter code here

        <input class="input-field login-button" type="submit" value="Sign In" id="login-form-login" tabindex="0">

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more details, (PowerShell) version, code snippets, exact error, [mcve], etc. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: as `iRon` stated ... how can anyone help you with code that you have not shown to any of us? [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry! I just updated the details. Please let me know if you have something that can help me fix this.